# How to use IsNumeric method in MonoDevelop by using Microsoft.VisualBasic reference?

Tags: c#, reference, monodevelop, isnumeric

What I am trying to do is to check whether the float input is a number or not. I am being asked to do so by using IsNumeric() method. The problem is that I am using MonoDevelop and I can't figure out why this doesn't work. It seems like I have added assembly reference which I need.

So from scratch. How do I do this? Do I have to add something to VB assembly reference? And, If that will still work when I will try to work in school on VisualStudio?

```
static void getBookInfo(Book book)
{
        Console.Write("Enter Book Title: ");
        book.Title = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Author's First Name: ");
        book.AuthorFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Author's Last Name: ");
        book.AuthorLastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Book Price: $");
        book.Price = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

The reference file with VB looks like this:

```
public class VBCodeProvider : CodeDomProvider
{
    // Constructors
    public VBCodeProvider ();
    public VBCodeProvider (IDictionary<string, string> providerOptions);

    // Methods
    public virtual ICodeCompiler CreateCompiler ();
    public virtual ICodeGenerator CreateGenerator ();
    public virtual TypeConverter GetConverter (Type type);
    public virtual void GenerateCodeFromMember (CodeTypeMember member, TextWriter writer, CodeGeneratorOptions options);

    // Properties
    public virtual string FileExtension { get; }
    public virtual LanguageOptions LanguageOptions { get; }
}
```

Regards. And thank you for help.

Some more info. On top of my page I do have:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

IsNumeric() method isn't listed when I try to type it (usually things are listed).

Another edit. So I could do this this way (but I do need to use the IsNumeric method so I wont loose any points from homework):

```
static void getBookInfo(Book book)
{
    bool isNumeric;
    float number;
    string numberInput;

    Console.Write("Enter Book Title: ");
        book.Title = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Author's First Name: ");
        book.AuthorFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Author's Last Name: ");
        book.AuthorLastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Book Price: $");
        numberInput = Console.ReadLine();

    isNumeric = float.TryParse(numberInput, out number);

    if (isNumeric)
        Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("not number");
}
```

Comment: Personally I do it the second way (your last edit)

Comment: Well. Yeah but I'm trying to not loose any points on my homework. Grumpy professor... Screw this, I'm installing VisualStudio through WINE!

Comment: If you are a student and you need .Net tools, you can get Windows Server 2008, Visual Studio Professional, and other tools at www.dreamspark.com for free (and legitimate).

Comment: Problem is... I'm using Ubuntu Natty (and I'm trying to stick with that.) So MonoDevelop seemed like a great choice for C# programming.

Comment: Well, never mind. WINE has a bug which can't install VisualStudio. I'm doing this the way I have presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a static method on the "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information" class. Even with that `using` you need to access it as

`Information.IsNumeric (someString)`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric.aspx

Comment: I will take a look into it. Will that cause problems in VisualStudio?

Comment: No, that's how C# works. You'd have to do the same thing in Visual Studio. I'm pretty sure you'd have to do the same thing in VB, if it weren't a special builtin.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. "Error CS0103: The name `information' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (Lab_6)"

Comment: Unlike VB.NET, case matters in C#. Use "Information", not "information".

Answer (score 1):

If the pain of attempting to link to the Visual Basic assemblies is too much, you might find the decimal.TryParse() method performs a suitably similar functionality with few drawbacks.

An example of its use can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx

Comment: only if i would VS :) c# here.. This was my homework assignment a while ago, and it did not involve using parse methods.